# Disable CTRL-V paste in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to disable copy paste via keyboard (ctrl-V) into CKEditor text box without changing CKEDitor code.
Is it possible to do this with some kind of configuration?

I tried with:

```
config.keystrokes = [];
```

But it did not work, obviously.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to disable paste in ckeditor

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("Answer");
 
editor.on('paste', function (evt) {
     evt.cancel();
});
```